# Vtiger - Editing the Picklistutils.php script to select certain values for custom fields

Tags: php, vtiger, vtigercrm, dynamic-picklist-vtiger

I want to modify the sql statement that selects the picklist values for my custom field

Modified the custom field table by adding a `createdtime` column and updated the values. I added custom code to the functions in the `picklistutils.php`:

```
if ($adb->$fieldName == cf_879) {
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM vtiger_cf_879 WHERE createdtime LIKE '2019-08%';
    $result = $adb-> query($sql);
    $count = $adb->num_rows($result);
}
```

The pick list values should only show the fields in the database with the created time in 2019-08

Comment: full summary on https://discussions.vtiger.com/discussion/190494/developers-editing-the-picklistutils-php-script-to-select-certain-values-for-custom-fields/p1?new=1

Comment: i agree with the posters on the discussion channel that this is a bad idea. however if you are stuck doing it, for debugging, you can try adding a die inside that function to see if it ever reaches there.

Comment: also, what is the data type of the createdtime column?

Comment: Hi @pinaki it is of TIMESTAMP